# How can I loosen the letter spacing in my bold-faced headers?

Tags: spacing, letterspacing

When headers are set to bold face, they appear too tight please see MWE.

```
%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\documentclass{book} %
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} %
\usepackage{titletoc} %
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % no apparent effect
\usepackage[utf8,latin1]{inputenx} %
\usepackage{txfonts} % needed for cross but when placed last, S is wrong
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} %
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=normalsize,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space,position=below]{caption} %
\usepackage[position=below,textfont=normal,labelfont=bf]{caption,subfig} % 
\usepackage[dvips=true,pdftex=true,verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop} % a4=210mm x 297mm
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
%
\definecolor{ThemeColour}{rgb}{0.45,0.00,0.45} %
\definecolor{ThemeGrey}{rgb}{0.92,0.92,0.92}

\newtcolorbox{sectionbox}[2][]{nobeforeafter, boxsep=4.4pt,boxrule=1.2pt,arc=3pt,outer arc=3.2pt,width=\linewidth, % 
coltitle=white,colbacktitle=ThemeColour,after=\hfill,colframe=black,colback=ThemeGrey,title={#2},fonttitle=\bfseries,#1} %

\titleformat{\section} %
  {\normalfont\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont} % 
  {}{0pt}
{\begin{sectionbox}
{\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont{Section\hspace{5.6pt}\thetitle}}{{#1}\vspace{-2.4pt}} %
\end{sectionbox}}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{10pt}{5.4pt}[0pt] %
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} %

\begin{document}
\vspace{6pt}
\section{The bolding of the header appears to tighten the kerning - especially words like: lining; \hspace{1.2pt}I just want it about 2pc looser}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd recommend `microtype` or `soul`, but it's no fun to play with snippets. I bet if you provided a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)), you'd get a fairly quick response.

Comment: MWE added as you suggest.

Comment: Stealing sheep? `;-)` http://webtypography.net/2.1.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `microtype`, you can automatically adjust the tracking of all fonts in bold face by adding the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{bold}
   { encoding = *, series = bf* }
\SetTracking
   [ unit = 1pc ]
   { encoding = *, series = bf* }
   { 20 }
```

If you only want the sectioning font adjusted, remove the `\DeclareMicrotypeSet` command and the `tracking` option from the above, and add `\lsstyle` where needed, in your example here:

```
\titleformat{\section} %
  {\normalfont\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{12}{16}\lsstyle\selectfont} % <--
  {}{0pt}
  {\begin{sectionbox}
  {\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont{Section\hspace{5.6pt}\thetitle}}{{#1}\vspace{-2.4pt}}%
  \end{sectionbox}}
```

---

**Update**

As requested, here is your example with my suggested additions:

(Letterspacing with `microtype` doesn't work in dvi mode, so an alternative solution with the `soul` package is provided too. Note that automatic tracking adjustment for all bold fonts is not possible with `soul`.)

```
%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\documentclass{book} %
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage[explicit,pagestyles]{titlesec} % <-- added option `pagestyles'
\usepackage{titletoc} %
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % no apparent effect
\usepackage[utf8,latin1]{inputenx} %
\usepackage{txfonts} % needed for cross but when placed last, S is wrong
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} %
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=normalsize,labelfont=bf,labelsep=space,position=below]{caption} %
\usepackage[position=below,textfont=normal,labelfont=bf]{caption,subfig} % 
\usepackage[dvips=true,pdftex=true,verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop} % a4=210mm x 297mm
\usepackage{tikz} % tikz - essential
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
%
\definecolor{ThemeColour}{rgb}{0.45,0.00,0.45} %
\definecolor{ThemeGrey}{rgb}{0.92,0.92,0.92}

\newtcolorbox{sectionbox}[2][]{nobeforeafter, boxsep=4.4pt,boxrule=1.2pt,arc=3pt,outer arc=3.2pt,width=\linewidth, % 
coltitle=white,colbacktitle=ThemeColour,after=\hfill,colframe=black,colback=ThemeGrey,title={#2},fonttitle=\bfseries,#1} %
\titleformat{\section} %
  {\normalfont\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont} % 
  {}{0pt}
  {\begin{sectionbox}
  {\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont{Section\hspace{5.6pt}\thetitle}}{{#1}\vspace{-2.4pt}} %
   \end{sectionbox}}

% ------ additions -------
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf % <-- enable tracking in pdf mode
\microtypesetup{tracking=true} 
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{bold}
   { encoding = *, series = bf* }
\SetTracking
   [ unit = 1pc ]
   { encoding = *, series = bf* }
   { 20 }
\newcommand\lscaps[2][80]{\textls[#1]{#2}}
\else % <-- alternative with soul
\usepackage{soul}
\soulregister\hspace7
\sodef\lscaps{}{.1em} {.4em plus.08em minus.06em}{.4em plus.15em minus.83em}%
\sodef\lsbold{}{.02em}{.3em plus.08em minus.06em}{.3em plus.15em minus.83em}%
\titleformat{\section} % <-- change title format, adding letterspacing
  {\normalfont\bfseries\itshape\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont} % 
  {}{0pt}
  {\begin{sectionbox}
  {\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\lsbold{Section\hspace{5.6pt}\thetitle}}{\lsbold{#1}\vspace{-2.4pt}} %
   \end{sectionbox}}
\fi
\newpagestyle{main}{% <-- change header definitions to accommodate letterspacing
  \sethead[\thepage][][\slshape \MakeUppercase{\lscaps{\chaptername\ \thechapter. \ \chaptertitle}}] % even
  {\slshape \thesection. \ \MakeUppercase{\lscaps{\sectiontitle}}}{}{\thepage}} % odd 
\pagestyle{main}
% ------ end additions -------

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{10pt}{5.4pt}[0pt] %
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} %

\begin{document}
\vspace{6pt}
\section[Bolding of the header -- lining]{The bolding of the header appears to tighten the kerning -- especially words like: lining; \hspace{1.2pt}I just want it about 2pc looser}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output -- tracking is adjusted both for bold text and for the all-caps running header:

[image: example]

Comment: Robert - tried exactly what you suggest (copy and paste) - using the global method - no errors, but with [unit=1pc] and {20}, the tracking remains the same.  Also tried [unit=3pc] and {30} no change.

Comment: @keith77777 ... works for me if I put the snippet at the end of the preamble from your example code. Which engine are you using? Or are you perhaps talking about the all-caps running header? (because this could also do with some more tracking)

Comment: Robert - I'm sure you are correct and something is over-riding things in my case.  Engine: is that MiKTeX 2.9 with amsbook?  Would you be kind enough to edit my MWE - including, if you don't mind, the "all caps running header" you mention.

Comment: @keith77777 see update...

Comment: Robert  I copied and pasted your tex file into a new document.  It gives errors and no output.  When I comment-out your \newpagestyle lines, the errors disappear, but the section head has no words in it.  I tried changing the colours, but no effect.  However, I can see your output is perfect.

Comment: Which errors do you get? And which engine are you using? (pdftex, luatex, xetex?)

Comment: Robert  Your question caused me to investigate further.  Using latex to dvi, I get the errors and no effect; using latex to pdf - perfect.  But I like to use the former during editing as it is quicker.  Is there a simple remedy?

Comment: @keith77777 No, letterspacing is not possible in dvi mode. What you could is to enable letterspacing only for pdf mode, so that you can still compile the document without errors during the editing phase. (see update)

Comment: @keith77777 I've added an alternative solution with the `soul` package for dvi mode.

Comment: Robert  Thank you - problem solved for dvi and pdf.